# Different methods for different outputs

Tags: c#

I have this code: that prints an output and I don't want to repeat it again to calculate the total for the cost:

```
public void printCost(List<c_flightRotationAircraft> fRAList,
    List<c_itineraryDistFra> iDFraList, HashSet<string> distinctAircraft, HashSet<int> distinctItinerary,
    List<c_position> positionList, List<c_airportAircraft> aAList, c_config config)
{
    c_files f = new c_files();
    double pDC = passengerDelayCost(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); // Passenger delay cost
    double oCC = outboundCancelCost(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); // Outbound cancellation cost
    double iCC = inboundCancelCost(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); // Inbound cancellation cost
    double cLC = cancelLegalCost(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); // Cancellation Legal Compensation Cost
    double dLC = delayLegalCost(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); // Delay legal cost
    double fOCD = flightOperatingCostDecrease(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); //Penalties for non-compliant location of aircraft
    /*
    f.insertAircraftPositionEndRtw(distinctAircraft, fRAList, config, positionList, aAList); // inserts the aircraft in the airports (aAList) List
    double pNcLA = penaltyNonCompliantLocationAircraft(fRAList, iDFraList,
    distinctAircraft, positionList, aAList, config); // Penalties for non-compliant location of aircraft
    */
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Passenger delay cost: {0}", pDC.ToString("#.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("Outbound cancellation cost: {0}", oCC.ToString("#.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("Inbound cancellation cost: {0}", iCC.ToString("#.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("Cancellation Legal Compensation Cost: {0}", cLC.ToString("#.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("Delay legal cost: {0}", dLC.ToString("#.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("Flight operating cost decrease: {0}", fOCD.ToString("#.##"));
    //Console.WriteLine("Penalties for non-compliant location of aircraft: {0}", pNcLA.ToString("#.##"));
}
```

What is the simple way to have 3 methods: one for calculating the values, another for printing the costs and a third one to sum the total cost?

Comment: One thing you should always remember, a function (even Class) should have one and only one function.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of setup you can remove much of this code and do it all in a loop.

First, you need to define a class that can contain the description and amount for each cost.

```
class CostRecord
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

We need to associate each record with a function that can compute the cost, so we add one more property, `ComputationFunction`. The prototype is very complicated due to the nature of your code.

```
class CostRecord
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public Func
        <
            List<c_flightRotationAircraft>, 
            List<c_itineraryDistFra>, 
            HashSet<string>, 
            HashSet<int>,
            List<c_position>,
            List<c_airportAircraft>,
            c_config,
            double
        > 
        ComputationFunction { get; set; }
}
```

Now we need a list of these, which could look like this:

```
private List<CostRecord> _costRecords = new List<CostRecord>();
```

And we need to initialize it somewhere, possibly in your constructor:

```
_costRecords.Add(new CostRecord { Name = "Passenger delay cost",
                                  ComputationFunction = passengerDelayCost });
_costRecords.Add(new CostRecord { Name = "Outbound cancellation cost",
                                  ComputationFunction = outboundCancelCost });
_costRecords.Add(new CostRecord { Name = "Inbound cancellation cost",
                                  ComputationFunction = inboundCancelCost });
_costRecords.Add(new CostRecord { Name = "Cancellation Legal Compensation Cost",
                                  ComputationFunction = cancelLegalCost });
_costRecords.Add(new CostRecord { Name = "Delay legal cost",
                                  ComputationFunction = delayLegalCost });
_costRecords.Add(new CostRecord { Name = "Flight operating cost decrease",
                                  ComputationFunction = flightOperatingCostDecrease });
```

Now that all that setup is done, our solution is very short:

```
    c_files f = new c_files();

    foreach(var r in _costRecords)
    {
        r.Amount = r.ComputationFunction(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctAircraft, distinctItinerary, positionList, aAList, config);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:#.##}", r.Name, r.Amount);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Total cost: {0}", _costRecords.Sum( r => r.Amount));
```

Comment: Another idea would be to override `ToString()` in the `CostRecord` class (`return $"{Name}: {Amount:#.##}";` so that in the `foreach` you could just do `Console.WriteLine(r);`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to see where you are having trouble.

But why don't you create one method to retrieve the values to an object (a custom class object). This method can perform any calculations needed.

Then, create a method that takes that object and prints the values. And make another that takes that object and calculates totals.

If that doesn't answer your question, can you be more detailed about what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the method only once, why you don't return the sum as return-value of the method? This way you can use the sum-value outside the method:

```
public double printCost(List<c_flightRotationAircraft> fRAList,
        List<c_itineraryDistFra> iDFraList, HashSet<string> distinctAircraft, HashSet<int> distinctItinerary,
        List<c_position> positionList, List<c_airportAircraft> aAList, c_config config)
    {
        c_files f = new c_files();
        double pDC = passengerDelayCost(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); // Passenger delay cost
        double oCC = outboundCancelCost(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); // Outbound cancellation cost
        double iCC = inboundCancelCost(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); // Inbound cancellation cost
        double cLC = cancelLegalCost(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); // Cancellation Legal Compensation Cost



double dLC = delayLegalCost(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); // Delay legal cost
    double fOCD = flightOperatingCostDecrease(fRAList, iDFraList, distinctItinerary, config); //Penalties for non-compliant location
 of aircraft
        /*

f.insertAircraftPositionEndRtw(distinctAircraft, fRAList, config, positionList, aAList); // inserts the aircraft in the airports (aAList) List
    double pNcLA = penaltyNonCompliantLocationAircraft(fRAList, iDFraList,
        distinctAircraft, positionList, aAList, config); // Penalties for non-compliant location of aircraft
    */
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Passenger delay cost: {0}", pDC.ToString("#.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("Outbound cancellation cost: {0}", oCC.ToString("#.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("Inbound cancellation cost: {0}", iCC.ToString("#.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("Cancellation Legal Compensation Cost: {0}", cLC.ToString("#.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("Delay legal cost: {0}", dLC.ToString("#.##"));
    Console.WriteLine("Flight operating cost decrease: {0}", fOCD.ToString("#.##"));
    //Console.WriteLine("Penalties for non-compliant location of aircraft: {0}", pNcLA.ToString("#.##"));

return pDC + oCC + ... // whatever you want to sum.
}
```